# Green`s function of bending equation with damping term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, greens-function

Suppose I have Green`s function of initial-boundary value problem
$$
\frac{\partial^4w}{\partial x^4}+\alpha^2\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial t^2}=f(x,t),~ \alpha\neq 0,~ 0<x<l,~ t>0,
$$
$$
w = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=0,~ x=0,l,~ t\geq0,
$$
$$
w=w_0(x),~~ \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=w_0^1(x),~ t=0,~ 0\leq x\leq l.
$$

How to find Green`s function for corresponding initial-boundary value problem for equation
$$
\frac{\partial^4w}{\partial x^4}+\alpha^2\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial t^2}+\beta\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=f(x,t),~ \beta>0,~ 0<x<l,~ t>0.
$$

Comment: could u be a bit more specific what kind of problems show up if u include the damping term?

Comment: For example if there are viscous dampers attached to the beam, you get the second equation. If the dampers are filled with visco-elastic material, you get $$\beta\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}+\gamma w,$$ $\gamma>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting
$$
u(x,t)=\exp\left[\frac{\beta}{2}t\right]w(x,t),
$$
into
$$
\frac{\partial^4w}{\partial x^4}+\alpha^2\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial t^2}+\beta\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=f(x,t),~ \beta>0,~ 0<x<l,~ t>0.
$$
we arrive at
$$
\frac{\partial^4u}{\partial x^4}+\alpha^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\beta^2}{4}u=\exp\left[\frac{\beta}{2}t\right]f(x,t),~ \beta>0,~ 0<x<l,~ t>0.
$$
Green`s function of that equation is known:
$$
G\left(x,\xi,t\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\varphi_k\left(x\right)\varphi_k\left(\xi\right)}{\left|\left|\varphi_k\right|\right|^2}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(t\sqrt{\alpha^2\lambda_n^2-\frac{\beta^2}{4}}\right)}{\sqrt{\alpha^2\lambda_n^2-\frac{\beta^2}{4}}},
$$
in which $\varphi_n$ and $\lambda_n$ are the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the equation
$$
\varphi''''-\lambda^4\varphi=0,
$$
subject to appropriate boundary conditions.

Comment: not particularly crucial, but should we consider when $\alpha^2\lambda_n^2-\frac{\beta^2}{4}<0$? use $\sinh$ instead?

Comment: Why should one do that?

Comment: Ah, I see it's fine if $sin$ accepts complex argument. ~~